# Sort is not working as expected in after applying group sort ion solr

Tags: solr

im using solr 4.3.0 where i need to sort(asc/desc) from the minimum values of each group.

Im using below query to achieve the group.sort based on price as below,

Query:group.field=id&group.ngroups=true&group.sort=price_USD+asc&group=true&group.facet=true&group.limit=1
Result:

```
{
  "grouped": {
    "category": {
      "matches": 9,
      "groups": [
        {
          "groupValue": "11121",
          "doclist": {
            "numFound": 3,
            "start": 0,
            "docs": [
              {
                "id": "233",
                "catentry_id": "ProductBean",
                "price_USD": 24,
                "category": "11121",
                "version": 1566834290000396300
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "groupValue": "111",
          "doclist": {
            "numFound": 3,
            "start": 0,
            "docs": [
              {
                "id": "2",
                "catentry_id": "ProductBean",
                "price_USD": 24,
                "category": "111",
                "version": 1566833543360807000
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "groupValue": "11112",
          "doclist": {
            "numFound": 3,
            "start": 0,
            "docs": [
              {
                "id": "22",
                "catentry_id": "ProductBean",
                "price_USD": 22,
                "category": "11112",
                "version": 1566833809098276900
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but applying sort to the query is not working as expected since it is considering all the values from each group not restricting to the minimum value from each group.

Kindly help me on this

Answer (score 0):

`group.sort` will sort the documents within a group. So in your case, the results within a group will be sorted based on the `price_USD` field but your groups will be sorted based on the score.

In order to sort groups relative to each other, also use the sort parameter.
Append `&sort=price_USD asc` to your query.

See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) for more information.

Comment: My requirement is to sort the min value(price_USD )from each group can i sort according to it or else do i need to any customization for it

Comment: So you want to sort your groups based on the minimum value from each group. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried this out? This logic should work. Since you're limiting to 1 result per group and sorting based on price, only the minimum value will be returned and the groups therefore should sort according to the minimum price.

Comment: yea sorting by minimum(asc) price is sorting correctly but i want to sort minimum in desc where i need to consider minimum value from each group.but it is considering maximum price from each group.

Comment: To be clear, you are putting `group.sort=price_USD asc&sort=price_USD asc` along with your group limiting params right?

Comment: yea im putting limit as 2 but it is considering all values in the grp for sorting.but i need to consider only the lowest value from each group for sorting either asc/desc in sort price_usd asc/desc